# Can I minimize inputs inside menu switches?

Tags: geometry-nodes

hey I'm trying to make my node groups simpler by hiding values on default.
this video shows what i mean.

is this possible?

thanks for any help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found something close enough to help me sort out my nodes. its called panels.
you can minimise them and maximise them to hide sockets so its not automatic but close enough for now

[image]